# Facebook.init callback not called

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, callback

We have a Facebook canvas application that is built in Flash and makes use of the Facebook actionscript API. This app has been working perfectly fine for over a year but as of this week, it has broken and there have been no changes to the code.

The app uses GraphAPI_Web_1_8_1.swc and the problem is that the callback from Facebook.init is no longer being called.

A number of people have had this same issue and a workaround has been posted in various forums that supposedly fixes the problem: http://ederchrono.com/blog/2012/05/09/fixing-fb-graph-api-for-as3/

We have tried this but it has not worked for our application and the bug still persists.

Does anyone have a solution to this bug?

Many Thanks

Comment: I am having the same problem. Not resolved yet and we are at end of November.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

id and name attribute of the `<object>` tag have to be set to identical values. IIRC, activeX browsers use "name", all others "id".

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/issues/detail?id=416&sort=-id) the solution

In few words you have to replace "FB.JSON" with "JSON" in FacebookJSBridge.as

Comment: Thanks Marco but the link that I posted in the initial post (http://ederchrono.com/blog/2012/05/09/fixing-fb-graph-api-for-as3/) actually replaces FB.JSON with JSON exactly how you describe BUT this does not fix the problem for our application.